# AVAssetWriter crashing with HEVC With Alpha - looking for workaround

Tags: swift, avfoundation, scenekit, avassetwriter

Since upgrading to macOS 12.3, Apple's sample code for writing HEVC with Alpha is crashing.

[Sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_playback_and_selection/using_hevc_video_with_alpha) - project: HEVC-Videos-With-Alpha-AssetWriting

Here's the crash
[image]

For some reason, there is no `pixelBufferPool`. This worked perfectly before the update.

**Finding a workaround**

I've filed FB9972239, but I'd love to work around this issue as I have users who need this.

**What I've tried**

- Changing the `AVVideoCodecKey` to `AVVideoCodecType.h264`. This works, but obviously without the alpha channel.
- Changing the codec to `AVVideoCodecType.proRes4444`. This doesn't crash, but there is no alpha channel. I find this strange, since ProRes4444 supports alpha.

**Update**

Changing the output settings to the below prevents the crash.

It's better than nothing, but it does not seem ideal to not be able to control alpha quality, and non-temporal compression must result in worse quality and file size?

```swift
            let outputSettings = [
                AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.hevcWithAlpha,
                AVVideoWidthKey: ExportSettings.width,
                AVVideoHeightKey: ExportSettings.height,
                AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: [
                    kVTCompressionPropertyKey_AllowTemporalCompression : false
                                                 ]
                ] as [String: Any]
```

Comment: Even Apple Compressor suffers from this system bug. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253725635

Comment: Seems to be a Pro/Max specific issue, and not just HEVC With Alpha, and also affecting other consumer apps. Here is a similar report where Apple confirms the bug https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/694622?login=true